# E(XY) = E(X).E(Y|X) . Is this true for mean = zero.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I know that Joint Probability density function for two random functions $X$ and $Y$

$$P(XY) = P(X)\cdot P(Y|X)\tag{1}$$

But I just read in a set of lecture notes that for E(X)=E(Y)=0

$$E(XY) = E(X)\cdot E(Y|X)\tag{2}$$

I also know that $E(X) =$ Multiplication of $P(X)$ with $x$ and subsequent Integration over $x$

Hence, I don't see how equation (2) stands true. Any ideas? Is it wrongly written.

Comment: What do mean by mean of X and Y=0? Do you mean $E(X|Y=0)$?

Comment: After your edits the right hand side of equation (2) is 0. That means you need to prove that $E(XY)=0$.

Comment: OK. I got it. Equation 2 is wrong and does not exist. However, whoever visits this question in future, do not confuse (2) with E(XY) = E(X) E(Y), which stands true if X and Y are independent and if their individual mean is zero.

Comment: Note that, $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and expectations exists. It is not needed that individuals mean has to be zero.

Comment: Yeah Sorry. That is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation (1) is misleading.   The *joint density function* of two random variables is *not* related to their product.   Further we more commonly use $f$ for probability *density* functions, rather than $\mathsf P$.  So the joint PDF is:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$$

The expected value of the product of two random variables is then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[XY]
 & = \iint_{\mathcal{X\times Y}} xy\; f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y \operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
 & = \iint_{\mathcal{X\times Y}} xy\;f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)\operatorname d y \operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
 & = \int_\mathcal X x\left(\int_\mathcal{Y\mid X=x} y\;f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\operatorname d y\right)f_X(x)\operatorname dx
\\[1ex] & = \int_\mathcal X x\;\mathsf E[Y\mid X=x]\;f_X(x)\operatorname dx
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf E[X\;\mathsf E[Y\mid X]]
\end{align}$$

Which is **not** the same thing as: $\mathsf E[X]\;\mathsf E[Y\mid X]$

Comment: What is $\mathcal{Y}\mid \mathcal{X}=x$?

Comment: The support of Y given X=x